# How to delete an object with multiple children in Firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete an object with multiple children in my Firebase database. My data is setup like so:

[image: Attempting to delete, -KK4kr7tBDN-2whVrjbJ]

I am running the following code in my iOS app:

```
[[ref child:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/playlistSongs/%@", playlistObject[@"firebaseID"], nil]] removeValueWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref) {
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"DELETED!");
                        }
                    }];
```

When this code runs, DELETED! is outputted in the log. However the object still remains in my firebase database. Is it possible to delete objects with multiple children? Looking at the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#delete_data), it suggests that I should be able to do so. It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: what is the value of this `playlistObject[@"firebaseID"]` ? also why do you use `,nil` ?

Comment: playlistObject[@"firebaseID"] is equal to -KK4kr7tBDN-2whVrjbJ. I used to make sure I am deleting the correct collection of children.

Comment: Deleting the parent node, will delete all children too. So there must be something else going wrong. But from the snippet it's hard to say what that may be. It might be worth enabling debug logging by calling [`FIRDatabase.setLoggingEnabled()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database.html#method-detail) and checking what shows up.

Comment: `[FIRDatabase setLoggingEnabled:YES]` sorted it out for me. I was reusing `ref` therefore my new path was appending to an old path.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes simpler is better:

```
Firebase *ref = path to the parent node
[ref setValue: nil];
```

Comment: this is for to delete single row chat from table view?

Comment: @DishantRajput This is a technique to remove or delete a row from Firebase. The Original question was *How to delete an object with multiple children in Firebase?* Instead of removing all of the children, setting the parent node to nil does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

remove value function is work for me

```
[[[_ref child:@"playlistSongs"] child:snapshot.key] removeValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be better if you stand "playlistSongs" and call updateChildValues with nil param.

Comment: How do I go about doing this? I thought updateChildValues was nonnil

Comment: That would make no difference: deleting a parent node will delete all children. Likewise deleting all children will also delete the parent node. Something else must be going wrong.